# Are the Nausicaans and the Kradin related?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

In the Star Trek Voyager episode [Nemesis](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Nemesis_(episode)), Chakotay is shot down on a planet and eventually encounters a race called the Kradin.

[image]

The Kradin look very similar to the Nausicaans that are relatively common to the Next Gen and DS9 series.

[image: Nausicaan]

Is there anything in canon that suggests these two races are related? And if so, how?

Comment: They don't look any more similar to me than humans and, say, the Ocampa.  I see no reason to think they're any more closely related than [any other two humanoid species](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Ancient_humanoid).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Nausicaan) makes the statement that:

> In some ways, Nausicaans were physically similar to the Chalnoth and
>   the Kradin. (TNG: "Tapestry", "Allegiance"; VOY: "Nemesis")

However, I can find no solid evidence on Memory Alpha or Beta that they were in any way related.

I would not be surprised though if they were in some way related; considering we learn in *Voyager* that several species from Earth have traveled to the Delta quadrant, including the [Voth](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Voth), it is certainly possible that a group of Nausicaans left their homeworld and ended in the Delta Quadrant (or vice versa).  This is just speculation though; I can't find anything to support or deny that claim, other than the fact that we do know such an occurrence has happened in the *Star Trek* canon universe before.